# Assigning scrollLeft with (scrollWidth - clientWidth) is not working properly

Tags: javascript, scroll

I assigned `element.scrollLeft` with `element.scrollWidth - element.clientWidth`

```
element.scrollLeft = element.scrollWidth - element.clientWidth;
```

And received the following:

[image]

Here is the console log for `element.scrollLeft` as well as for `element.scrollWidth - element.clientWidth` as follows:

```
console.log("Max scroll width: " + (element.scrollWidth - element.clientWidth));
console.log("Actual scroll after assignment: " + element.scrollLeft);
```

Why am `element.scrollLeft` value doesn't match `element.scrollWidth - element.clientWidth`?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but wasn't able to. Here is my example: https://codepen.io/Yona-Appletree/pen/Vqzqba Please produce a running example of this failing so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: I know! Weird, right? I used codepen to test as well... I'm giving maintenance to this system. I'm starting to think this is probably something related to some CSS or css libs in use. But I thought that someone would imagine something about these 15 points, considering as well that it's about a scrollleft and about scrolling this to max. Already reviewed paddings, margins and nothing points to "15" or "7,5", or whatsoever.

Comment: Forgot to mention that even when I tried to add the diference after all the assignments (value += 15), it changes nothing. Really weird.